# Changing element into a textarea is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change element with following id into text area.

I don't know js very well so the problem may be really stupid right here.

It doesn't actually change anything right now. The id in variable is correct.

Any ideas please ?

```
<script>
function editComment(id){
    var thisId = "#" + id;
    $(thisId).html("<textarea></textarea>");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`html` only sets the *inner* HTML content of the matched elements. You should use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) instead:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  editComment("comment1");
});

function editComment(id){
  var thisId = "#" + id;
  $(thisId).replaceWith("<textarea></textarea>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comment1">Comment</div>
<button>Edit</button>
```